# Servo Torque question

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I recently bought a servo whose torque is 2.2kg/cm, if i wanted to rotate (using the servo) an item that weighs 6.8KG (15lbs) at a length of 0.4572M (18 inches) 60 degrees would it be possible?

Comment: Just doing the math would have taken less time than writing this question!  Also "KG" is not a unit of weight.

Answer (score 3):

I think the units for the servo torque should be $kg \cdot cm$.  Anyway, the torque required to rotate the mass if it is sticking 90 degrees out to the side is $(6.8\,kg)(0.4572 \,m)(9.8 \frac{m}{s^2}) = 30.5\, N \cdot m$.  The torque of your servo is $(2.2\,kg\cdot cm)(\frac{1m}{100cm})(9.8 \frac{m}{s^2})=0.216\,N\cdot m$.

So, the servo is drastically undersized for this application.

Comment: unless reduction gearing is used.

Comment: @ratchetfreak using the word "servo", even if the servo is a 360 degree rotation, and OP wants 60 degrees of rotation, the most you could get is a 1:6 torque multiplication, which means that the servo torque goes from 0.2 Nm to 1.2Nm, which is still far shy of the 30.5 Nm required for the stated load.